# Send a Cookie header field in relay request

Tags: relayjs

It looks like stock relay networklayer does'nt send a cookie header field with his request.
So I tried to add it by adding Cookie field like this:

```
Relay.injectNetworkLayer(
  new Relay.DefaultNetworkLayer('/graphql', {
    headers: {
      'Cookie': 'user=thibaut',
    },
  })
);
```

but still the Cookie field is not present in my post request.
If I replace 'Cookie' with 'Set-Cookie', IT IS in my post request...

I need my server to use cookies please help ! :)

Comment: Yes it is written in the fetch api that Cookie field is not supported.. don't know why. the relay post request do not set a cookie field, so there is no way to have access to httponly cookie server side under a relay post request since Relay.injectNetworkLayer is implemented browser side...

Comment: The [best docs I can find](https://github.com/github/fetch) for `fetch` (and specifically, these are polyfill docs) suggest that `{credentials: 'same-origin'}` and `{credentials: 'include'}` can be used to change cookie-sending behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set your cookies in the usual way (using browser APIs) then configure fetch as follows to have them sent along with each request:

```js
Relay.injectNetworkLayer(
  new Relay.DefaultNetworkLayer('/graphql', {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
  })
);
```

See also: https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/437

Comment: Where does the `Relay` object come from? It seems like there is no `injectNetworkLayer` function in the current relay version

Comment: Yeah! All of this stuff has moved. You should ask the question on Stack Overflow again, for the newest version of Relay, so that the new answer can be given for others to read.

Comment: I solved this issue by setting `{credentials: "include"}` on the `fetch` function. So no need to configure Relay itself. My frontend and backend run on different ports, so `"same-origin"` did not apply. After that I was getting CORS preflight errors even though I used a CORS middleware in express. It turned out `apollo-express-server` needs the `corsOptions` passed directly to the Apollo server, otherwise it won't work. Hope this helps someone