# How can I set a cookie with Relay?

Tags: cookies, graphql, graphql-js, relayjs, relay

I've got express js server code:

```
...
const server = new GraphQLServer({
  typeDefs: `schema.graphql`,
  resolvers,
  context: context => {
    let cookie = get(context, 'request.headers.cookie');
    return { ...context, cookie, pubsub };
  },
});
```

such that I can attach `cookie` to resolvers' requests:

```
...
method: 'GET',
headers: {
  cookie: context.cookie,
},
```

Now I want to be able to use Relay (as a GraphQL client) and I want to be able to attach a cookie to Relay's requests as well.

I've found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889938/send-a-cookie-header-field-in-relay-request) but it's not clear to me where can I insert that code:

```
Relay.injectNetworkLayer(
  new Relay.DefaultNetworkLayer('/graphql', {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
  })
);
```

since I don't import `Relay` in `Environment.js`.

Update: I tried to add

```
import { Relay, graphql, QueryRenderer } from 'react-relay';
Relay.injectNetworkLayer(
  new Relay.DefaultNetworkLayer('http://example.com/graphql', {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
  })
);
```

to a file where I send GraphQL queries (e.g., `client.js`), but it says that `Relay` is *undefined*.

Update #2: [this repo](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/294#issuecomment-202812616) looks interesting.